# Matching strings with underscores, lowercase ASCII letters, ASCII digits, hyphens or dots only not starting with dot and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need regular expression which could match a string like that

```
_test
123test
test
test_123
test-123
123.a
```

I created this regular expression:

```
/^[_0-9a-z][_.\-a-z0-9]*$/
```

However, I want to exclude a string if it only contains numbers.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What language is the one you are using? Note that in Ruby, to match the start and end of the string, you need `\A` (start) and `\z` (end) anchors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid matching a digit-only string, add a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)[_0-9a-z][_.\-a-z0-9]*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?![0-9]+$)` lookahead is triggered only once at the beginning of the string and will try to match one or more digits up to the end of string. If they are found, a match will be failed (no match will be returned) as the lookahead is *negative*.